# How Can i make all elements in div centered HTML5

Tags: html, center

i have tried all other way search on stackoverflow etc but couldn't found my answer
my div id is loginbox.

```
  <div id="loginbox">
<form action="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><label>Username:</label></td>
        <td><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Password:</label></td>
         <td><input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
</table> 
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the HTML, but what does your CSS look like?

Comment: Use Flexbox available in CSS3: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Robert I mean i want to do WITH Html5 Way ~ Validate HTML5 in Visual Studio

Comment: @YaserRanjha you can't do it only using HTML...

Comment: What do you mean with `HTML5 way`? There's no such thing related to what you're asking. This is merely CSS. But if you're really willing to do things on a nice/right way, stop using tables for layout purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your CSS, but considering just what's in your question, this should work:

```
#loginbox form table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TmY46/

And this isn't related to HTML5. It's purely CSS.

Comment: This Example Work For Me ThankQ

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you want to have:

```
#loginbox table { margin:auto; }
```

or

```
#loginbox * { text-align:center; }
```

or

```
#loginbox table * { margin:auto; }
```

or any combination!?

Answer (score 1):

First or all, you shouldnt use a table for that.
Anyway, something like that :

```
td{text-align:center;}
form input{display:block;margin:auto;}
```

If you really want to code in html5, i encourage you to use a different structure,
like :

```
<form>
<p><label>Username :</label><input type=text /><span style="clear:both"></span></p>
<p><label>Password :</label><input type=password /><span style="clear:both"></span></p>

<input type=submit vale="login" />
</form>
```

And in css :

```
form {margin:auto;}
form p{display:block;margin:3px 0;}
form input[type=text], form input[type=password]{float:left;width:150px;}
```

This is how i would do, it's cleaner and much flexible

Comment: Element 'div' cannot be nested in p Element According To HTML5

Comment: yes my bad, you can use any other element like a span to do the clear:BOTH job